# extend gsub and grepl to ignore substrings between given delimiters

Tags: r, regex, gsub, grepl

I want to be able to use `grepl()` and `gsub()` only outside of given sets of delimiters, for instance I want to be able to ignore text between quotes.

Here is my desired output :

```
grepl2("banana", "'banana' banana \"banana\"", escaped =c('""', "''"))
#> [1] TRUE
grepl2("banana", "'banana' apple \"banana\"", escaped =c('""', "''"))
#> [1] FALSE
grepl2("banana", "{banana} banana {banana}", escaped = "{}")
#> [1] TRUE
grepl2("banana", "{banana} apple {banana}", escaped = "{}")
#> [1] FALSE

gsub2("banana", "potatoe", "'banana' banana \"banana\"")
#> [1] "'banana' potatoe \"banana\""
gsub2("banana", "potatoe", "'banana' apple \"banana\"")
#> [1] "'banana' apple \"banana\""
gsub2("banana", "potatoe", "{banana} banana {banana}", escaped = "{}")
#> [1] "{banana} potatoe {banana}"
gsub2("banana", "potatoe", "{banana} apple {banana}", escaped = "{}")
#> [1] "{banana} apple {banana}"
```

Real cases might have quoted substrings in different amounts and order.

I have written the following functions which work for these cases, but they are clunky and `gsub2()` is not robust at all as it replaces the delimited content with placeholders temporarily, and these placeholders might be affected by subsequent operations.

```
regex_escape <-
function(string,n = 1) {
  for(i in seq_len(n)){
    string <- gsub("([][{}().+*^$|\\?])", "\\\\\\1", string)
  }
  string
}

grepl2 <- 
  function(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, 
           useBytes = FALSE, escaped =c('""', "''")){
    escaped <- strsplit(escaped,"")
    # TODO check that "escaped" delimiters are balanced and don't cross each other
    for(i in 1:length(escaped)){
      close <- regex_escape(escaped[[i]][[2]])
      open <- regex_escape(escaped[[i]][[1]])
      pattern_i <- sprintf("%s.*?%s", open, close)
      x <- gsub(pattern_i,"",x)
    }
    grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case, perl, fixed, useBytes)
  }

gsub2 <- function(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, 
                   fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, escaped =c('""', "''")){
  escaped <- strsplit(escaped,"")
  # TODO check that "escaped" delimiters are balanced and don't cross each other
  matches <- character()
  for(i in 1:length(escaped)){
    close <- regex_escape(escaped[[i]][[2]])
    open <- regex_escape(escaped[[i]][[1]])
    pattern_i <- sprintf("%s.*?%s", open, close)
    ind <- gregexpr(pattern_i,x)
    matches_i <- regmatches(x, ind)[[1]]
    regmatches(x, ind)[[1]] <- paste0("((",length(matches) + seq_along(matches_i),"))")
    matches <- c(matches, matches_i)
  }
  x <- gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case, perl, fixed, useBytes)
  for(i in seq_along(matches)){
    pattern <- sprintf("\\(\\(%s\\)\\)", i)
    x <- gsub(pattern, matches[[i]], x)
  }
  x
}
```

Is there a solution using regex and no placeholder ? Note that my current function supports multiple pairs of delimiters but I'll be satisfied by a solution that supports one pair only, and will not try to match substrings between simple quotes for instance.

It is also acceptable, to impose different delimiters, for instance `{` and `}` rather than 2 `"` or 2 `'` if it helps.

I am also fine with imposing `perl = TRUE`

Comment: Are you amenable to using `perl = TRUE`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `start/end_escape` arguments to provide the LHS and RHS of matched delimiters such as `{` and `}` without matching them in the wrong place (`}` as the LHS delimiter)

`perl = TRUE` allows look-around assertions. These assess the validity of the statements within them, *without capturing them in the pattern*. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) covers them pretty well.

You'll get an error in `perl = FALSE`, because [TRE](https://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/), the default regex engine for R, does not support them.

```
  gsub3 <- function(pattern, replacement, x, escape = NULL, start_escape = NULL, end_escape = NULL) {
      if (!is.null(escape) || !is.null(start_escape)) 
      left_escape <- paste0("(?<![", paste0(escape, paste0(start_escape, collapse = ""), collapse = ""), "])")
      if (!is.null(escape) || !is.null(end_escape))
      right_escape <- paste0("(?![", paste0(escape, paste0(end_escape, collapse = ""), collapse = ""), "])")
      patt <- paste0(left_escape, "(", pattern, ")", right_escape)
      gsub(patt, replacement, x, perl = TRUE)
    }
    gsub3("banana", "potatoe", "'banana' banana \"banana\"", escape = "'\"")
    #> [1] "'banana' potatoe \"banana\""
    gsub3("banana", "potatoe", "'banana' apple \"banana\"", escape = '"\'')
    #> [1] "'banana' apple \"banana\""
    gsub3("banana", "potatoe", "{banana} banana {banana}", escape = "{}")
    #> [1] "{banana} potatoe {banana}"
    gsub3("banana", "potatoe", "{banana} apple {banana}", escape = "{}")
    #> [1] "{banana} apple {banana}"
```

Below is `grepl3` - note this doesn't need `perl = TRUE` since we don't care what the pattern captures, just that it matches.

```
grepl3 <- function(pattern, x, escape = "'", start_escape = NULL, end_escape = NULL) {
  if (!is.null(escape) || !is.null(start_escape)) 
  start_escape <- paste0("[^", paste0(escape, paste0(start_escape, collapse = ""), collapse = ""), "]")
  if (!is.null(escape) || !is.null(end_escape))
  end_escape <- paste0("[^", paste0(escape, paste0(end_escape, collapse = ""), collapse = ""), "]")
  patt <- paste0(start_escape, pattern, end_escape)
  grepl(patt, x)
}

grepl3("banana", "'banana' banana \"banana\"", escape =c('"', "'"))
#> [1] TRUE
grepl3("banana", "'banana' apple \"banana\"", escape =c('""', "''"))
#> [1] FALSE
grepl3("banana", "{banana} banana {banana}", escape = "{}")
#> [1] TRUE
grepl3("banana", "{banana} apple {banana}", escape = "{}")
#> [1] FALSE
```

Edit:

This should solve the gsub without the problem mentioned by Andrew, as long as you are okay with a single set of paired operators. I think you could modify it to allow multiple delimiters though. Thanks for the fascinating problem, Found a new gem in `regmatches`!

```
gsub4 <-
  function(pattern,
           replacement,
           x,
           left_escape = "{",
           right_escape = "}") {
    # `regmatches()` takes a character vector and
    # output of `gregexpr` and friends and returns
    # the matching (or unmatching, as here) substrings
    string_pieces <-
      regmatches(x,
                 gregexpr(
                   paste0(
                     "\\Q",  # Begin quote, regex will treat everything after as fixed.
                     left_escape,
                     "\\E(?>[^", # \\ ends quotes.
                     left_escape,
                     right_escape,
                     "]|(?R))*", # Recurses, allowing nested escape characters
                     "\\Q",
                     right_escape,
                     "\\E",
                     collapse = ""
                   ),
                   x,
                   perl = TRUE
                 ), invert =NA) # even indices match pattern (so are escaped),
                                # odd indices we want to perform replacement on.
for (k in seq_along(string_pieces)) {
    n_pieces <- length(string_pieces[[k]])
  # Due to the structure of regmatches(invert = NA), we know that it will always
  # return unmatched strings at odd values, padding with "" as needed.
  to_replace <- seq(from = 1, to = n_pieces, by = 2)
  string_pieces[[k]][to_replace] <- gsub(pattern, replacement, string_pieces[[k]][to_replace])
}
    sapply(string_pieces, paste0, collapse = "")
  }
gsub4('banana', 'apples', "{banana's} potatoes {banana} banana", left_escape = "{", right_escape = "}")
#> [1] "{banana's} potatoes {banana} apples"
gsub4('banana', 'apples', "{banana's} potatoes {banana} banana", left_escape = "{", right_escape = "}")
#> [1] "{banana's} potatoes {banana} apples"
gsub4('banana', 'apples',  "banana's potatoes", left_escape = "{", right_escape = "}")
#> [1] "apples's potatoes"
gsub4('banana', 'apples', "{banana's} potatoes", left_escape = "{", right_escape = "}")
#> [1] "{banana's} potatoes"
```

Comment: looks great! I'll tick the mark as soon as I have time to check it

Comment: Very clever! Just a heads up, for `grepl3`, this solution may run into issues if the escaped character is included between start/end escapes. E.g., if someone went `banana's` in the text (and `'` was one of the escaped characters. Something to keep in mind or update.

Comment: A limitation of the gsub solution is that we can't use `"\\1"` as a replacement

Comment: You can use it but it will reset at each unescaped string piece. What is a practical example where you would need this?

Answer (score 3):

I tried my hand at `grepl2` but haven't had a crack (or thought of a clear solution) to `gsub2` yet. Anyway, this just removes any characters (excluding new lines) between the shortest pairs of the provided `escaped` characters. It should scale fairly well, too. If you go with this solution, you may want to build-in a check to make sure there are *pairs* of `escaped` character with no spaces (or otherwise adapt for the use of `substr()`. Hope this helps!

```
grepl3 <- 
  function(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, fixed = FALSE, 
           useBytes = FALSE, escaped =c('""', "''")){

    new_esc1 <- gsub("([][{}().+*^$|\\?])", "\\\\\\1", substr(escaped, 1, 1))
    new_esc2 <- gsub("([][{}().+*^$|\\?])", "\\\\\\1", substr(escaped, 2, 2))
    rm_pat <- paste0(new_esc1, ".*?", new_esc2, collapse = "|")
    new_arg <- gsub(rm_pat, "", arg)
    grepl(pattern, new_arg)

  }

grepl3(pattern = "banana", x = "'banana' apple \"banana\" {banana}", escaped =c("''", '""', "{}"))
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple regex solution using the negation operator in the character class. It only satisfies your simple case. I wasn't able to make it satisfy the paired multiple delimiter request:

```
grepl2 <- function(patt, escape="'", arg=NULL) {
             grepl( patt=paste0("[^",escape,"]", 
                                patt,
                                "[^",escape,"]"), arg) }

grepl2("banana", "'banana' apple \"banana\"", escape =c( "'"))
#[1] TRUE

grepl2("banana", "'banana' apple ", escape =c( "'"))
[#1] FALSE
```

Comment: Under this, `gsub2("banana", "potatoe", "{banana} banana {banana}", escaped = "{}")` will result in `"{banana}potatoe{banana}"`. That's the problem with negating a character set.

Comment: First, I'm not clear why thaty is the wrong answer. And... You really have two separate requests. You should split your question into a `grepl` versions and a `gsub` version.

Comment: It is stripping the spaces around the interior banana, because the pattern you're matching is saying "Not the escape characters". Thus the spaces are matched and also removed. If you include the spaces in the character set, you'll get no match at all.

Comment: Fine. Make two questions.

Comment: It's my question, not his :). I think these questions have too much in common to be separate. grepl is easier but a gsub solution will probably solve the grepl one as well, and grepl solutions can give clues for gsub

Answer (score 1):

My opinion is that you might need to separate the opening and closing brackets to make the code work properly.
Here I am making use of regex lookaround feature. This might not work universally (especially the lookback ?< matching operator) outside R.

```
grepl2 = function(pattern, x, escapes = c(open="\"'{", close="\"'}")){
     grepl(paste0("(?<![", escapes[[1]], "])",
                  pattern, 
                  "(?![", escapes[[2]], "])"), 
           x, perl=T)
}
grepl2("banana", "'banana' banana \"banana\"")
#> [1] TRUE
grepl2("banana", "'banana' apple \"banana\"")
#> [1] FALSE
grepl2("banana", "{banana} banana {banana}")
#> [1] TRUE
grepl2("banana", "{banana} apple {banana}")
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: Since we are using regex feature, just change grepl to gsub and it will work just fine.